# Wine supported automated batch conversion tool to convert Outlook .dbx files to .pst format on a linux system

Tags: linux, microsoft-outlook-2003, wine, outlook-express, file-conversion

This is continued from my earlier question https://superuser.com/questions/237471/batch-convert-outlook-express-dbx-files-to-ms-office-outlooks-pst-files-on-linu Please read the details there.

So, it looks so far like there are no available linux based `.dbx` to `.pst` converters. I am now thinking of trying out some windows based solutions on linux (using Wine). If someone knows of any Wine supported windows application which can be used as an automated process without any human involvement, please let me know. I assume that the software needs to be written to expect parameters through the command. Otherwise it is not possible to use it in an automated way.

Please note that, simply being able to use wine to start the application is not enough. It would display a UI to select an input file etc like this -

[image]

This would not work if the process has to be automated because a human being needs to select the filename and follow the steps. So, what is needed is actually a software/tool with Wine support - which expects the filename to be a parameter in the wine execute command.

I got the idea from this shell script given in http://www.netsick.org/read/4/convert-dbx-to-mbx-mailboxes-on-gnu-linux which executes another such converter (dbx2mbx) on linux through wine.

Thanks

Comment: There is a library available:
http://freshmeat.net/projects/libdbx/
This library will supposedly enable you to take .dbx files and convert them to mbox files. Mbox is more universally defined and is probably easier to get into .pst files.

Comment: @g19fanatic - thank you for the link. I will try it and put the results later.

Comment: @g19fanatic - do you know if mail attachments can be extracted in this process? The attachments are the main thing we want in this task.

Comment: I ran the `readdbx` module after extracting the `LibDBX` library successfully read the `.dbx` file and filled up an output file. However I did not get any attachment information in the output file.

Comment: I do not know as I have not personally tried out libDBX. I just know of it when i was also looking for a linux only solution to the .dbx to .mbox problem.